# Delete all text before a matching text in a file with Bash

Tags: bash

I have the following text in a file, and I would like to find the word `fox` and would like to delete the text before the word `fox` from the begining of the text. (including fox)

**I want to keep the whole text if there is no match.**

```
The quick 
brown fox 
jumps over 
the lazy dog
```

The requested outcome will be:

```
jumps over 
the lazy dog
```

The tool to be used is not important, but I'm with Msys on Windows, and not all the fancy tools are implemented here.

Things I tried:

```
var=$(echo "${raw}" | awk "/replaceme/{i++}i")
var=$(echo "${raw}" | sed -n "/replaceme/,${p}")
var=$(echo "${raw}" | sed -r -n -e "/replaceme/,${p}")
var=$(echo "${raw}" | sed "/replaceme/,$!d")
```

Thanks

Comment: What if there are multiple occurrences of the word? How would you deal with "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy fox"? Should the output be empty, or do you want to stop at first occurrence? Something else?

Comment: What should happen if there are more than one occurrences of the word fox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily in `awk`:

```
awk -v s="fox" '$0~s{re="^.*" s "[[:space:]]*"; sub(re, ""); }1' RS= file
jumps over
the lazy dog
```

When **pattern is not found**:

```
awk -v s="box" '$0~s{re="^.*" s "[[:space:]]*"; sub(re, ""); }1' RS= file
The quick
brown fox
jumps over
the lazy dog
```

**EDIT:** If you want to delete the text AFTER the match (including the line of match):

```
awk -v s="over" '$0~s{re="\n[^\n]*" s ".*$"; sub(re, ""); }1' RS= file
The quick
brown fox
```

Comment: This is fine for the case when `fox` is found, but not for the other, as the OP says: I want to keep the whole text if there is no match. Maybe it is needed to read the file twice: first to check this, next one to print depending on the condition.

Comment: it won't work if the input contains `brown fox blah \n
jumps over`

Comment: @fedorqui: Good point, I overlooked that part. Updated my answer to take care of it now.

Comment: @anubhava how about if I want to delete the text AFTER the match (inluding the line of match)? I am sorry but I don't understand this part to modify by myself `'$0~s{re="^.*" s "[[:space:]]*"; sub(re, ""); }1'`

Comment: Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only up to the first occurrence of `fox` you can have:

```
sed '1,/fox/d' file
```

Add `-i` as an option if you want to modify the file.

To delete lines up to the last occurrence:

```
awk 'BEGIN{start=1}{a[NR]=$0}/fox/{start=NR+1}END{for(i=start;i<=NR;++i)print a[i]}' file
```

To modify:

```
awk 'BEGIN{start=1;file=ARGV[1]}{a[NR]=$0}/fox/{start=NR+1}END{printf("")>file;for(i=start;i<=NR;++i)print a[i]}>file' file
```

Comment: this deletes the whole line containing the word `fox`, instead of only the words upto and including the word `fox`.

Comment: Well that seems to be what he wanted as shown in the output. Edit: Oh I get what you mean. Well let's see if it's what the OP really wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can go down the regex path with `/^.*fox(.+)|.+/s`.

This way, it will take everything from the text after the last occurence of `fox` and, if none found, everything.